# What's the meaning of "seems out of" and "proportion" in my sentence?

Tags: meaning, expressions

> The skull seems out of proportion with its thick, heavy body because it is so narrow and the jaws are delicate and fine.

What's the meaning of "seems out of" ?

Comment: No; it's 'seems' and 'out of proportion'. What these mean is better asked on ELL.

Answer (score 2):

**proportion** means the sense of scale between two shapes or objects. If something is *in proportion* with another object, it is the correct size in relation to it. If it is *out of proportion*, it is too big or small.

**seems** means *looks like it would be* and implies a level of uncertainty - the author does not say that it is definitely *out of proportion*, but that due to the size of the *thick, heavy body*, the *skull* looks like it should be bigger.

Answer (score 0):

it means an object doesn't look right